# DrawRect called once in subview

Tags: xcode, drawrect

Newbie to Xcode. set up a view controller with some custom buttons and text fields. added a small `UIview window` as a subView in my main view to draw a graph in. updating the graph by calling `[self.mySubView setNeedsDisplay]` in various methods in my `viewController`. MY `drawRect` in `mySubview` only gets called once and never again.